# App crashes - Memory Warning Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I'm creating an app, everything is okay while I just have this app opened on my ipad/iphone. But if I try to open 8 or 10 app's and then, I use my app, I receive memory warning and it crash with no error.

When I build my app, I analyze for memory problems and it's okay.

The other apps don't have this problems, they receive memory warnings but no crash. May be they do something in "-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning"? what can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode tools include a program called "Instruments". It's very helpful to see where the memory of your program is going to and what kind of objects allocate memory. You should have a look.

There are also some videos on youtube on how to use Instruments. Just search for "xcode instruments".

Comment: I opened it, and the graph is always increasing. I think that this is the problem... yes?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Simulate Memory Warning" in the simulator, best to do this when application is in the background to reproduce the issue.

The main thing to check is what is happening in the the viewDidLoad/viewDidUnload methods of your view controllers.  iOS will release your views in low memory conditions and they need to be recreated in viewDidLoad